# Go []int to rune

Tags: character-encoding, go

```
for pos, char := range s {
        fmt.Println( utf8.RuneLen(char) )
}
```

This code works in Go (pre v1) but doesn't work in Go1.

> cannot use char (type []int) as type rune in function argument

I ran go fix which updated the "utf8" import to "unicode/utf8", but now I get the previous err.

The [docs for rune](http://golang.org/doc/go1.html#rune) mention a trivial conversion will resolve this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted works in Go1. Assuming `s` is a string.

Make sure you aren't unexpectedly introducing or using some other variable named `char` which has type `[]int`, and make sure there are no typos in your code which would lead to unexpected usage of a different variable.

Comment: Woops s was of type [][]int. :D